# Tell Unity that an Axis isn't being pressed when it is

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, axis

Hello fellow programmers.

I'm here to ask you a very unusual question. I have created a game and in it when you hit a wall you bounce back but if you are still holding the key to go the direction you were going when you hit it it will just stay still, so I need to tell Unity that an Axis isn't being used anymore, is there a way to do this? Please note that I am using JavaScript and I am aware that it will be removed from Unity and that C# is better so don't comment that I should write code in C# please.

Code--
The movement:

```
if(Input.GetAxis("Forward") && isMovingBackward == false) {

        if(lastDir == "backward") {

            deaccelerate();
            brake();
            braking = true;
            canRotLeft = false;
            canRotRight = false;
        } if(!(lastDir == "backward") && canMoveForw == true) {

            accelerate();

            isMoving = true;
            isMovingForward = true;
            isMovingBackward = false;
            canRotLeft = true;
            canRotRight = true;

            lastDirForw();

            transform.Translate(Vector3(1, 0, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    if(!(Input.GetAxis("Forward"))) {

        isMovingForward = false;
    }

    if(!(Input.GetAxis("Backward"))) {

        isMovingBackward = false;
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Backward") && isMovingForward == false) {

        if(lastDir == "forward") {

            deaccelerate();
            brake();
            braking = true;
            canRotLeft = false;
            canRotRight = false;
        } if(!(lastDir == "forward") && canMoveBack == true) {

            accelerate();

            isMoving = true;
            isMovingBackward = true;
            ifMovingForward = false;
            breakingBack = false;
            canRotLeft = true;
            canRotRight = true;

            lastDirBack();

            transform.Translate(Vector3(1, 0, 0) * -speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

The lastDir functions:

```
function lastDirForw() {

    if(collided == true) {

        brake();
        canMoveBack = false;
        lastDir = "backward";
    } else {

        canMoveBack = true;
        lastDir = "forward";
    }
}

function lastDirBack() {

    if(collided == true) {

        brake();
        canMoveForw = false;
        lastDir = "forward";
    } else {

        canMoveForw = true;
        lastDir = "backward";
    }
}
```

Comment: Include your code - we can't help you if we can't see it!

Comment: Rather than attempting to override inputs, which will probably be headache-inducing and require you to add in more flags, checks, etc., how about taking a physics-based approach? Change your movement controls to `AddForce()` to the player, rather than whatever you're presently doing (I can't tell what since you hide your `accelerate()` and `deaccelerate()` implementations). Upon hitting a wall, reflect the player's velocity vector, multiply it by some value, and apply it to the player with as an impulse `AddForce()`. Problem solved(?). (Will add answer should more details be provided.)

Comment: accelerate and deaccelerate just change the speed. But I fixed this by creating a bool called collided and if you hit the wall it is set to true and if you hit the wall while collided is true and going forward you will go backwards and opposite if going backwards. This also fixed my collision problem that I had where the car glitches through the wall. Thanks anyways :) I love speaking to other programmers.

Comment: I managed to solve this same issue without the physics engine. All I did was store the value returned by the axis in a temp variable. I then check to see if I was colliding in the direction I wanted to head, if I was then I would set the temp variable to 0 and use that to move my object. If it wasn't 0 then it would move in the direction that was being pressed. I totally avoided all colliders with this method and I was using a grid of tiles. My "collision check" was checking the adjacent tiles to my object and if they were un walkable then it was colliding.

Comment: I would probably have to agree with @Serlite - `AddForce()` would be a lot easier to implement and to get your head around :)